# I want to concatenate two fields with the same string in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, field, concatenation

I have the following piece of code where i am concatenating events to the ID.

```
select concat('events-', eventid) as eventid,eventsource from events
```

However i want to add the "event" prefix to the field eventsource as well. How do i do this?
I am using postgresql 9.1.

Comment: Can't you just apply the same formula the other field ? Or I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question, but this should do it:

```
select concat('events-', eventid) as eventid,
       concat('event', eventsource) as eventsource
from events
```

Note that you can also use the (standard ANSI) concatenation operator for this:

```
select 'events-'||eventid as eventid,
       'event'||eventsource as eventsource
from events
```